# Can a button from the main page call a class to enter information into the first page?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want A button on my main page form to call for a separate class and for said separate class to write information into the main page text box.

I have tried in C# uwp app to send a message from the button on click event and a receive message from the separate class it didn't work.

...

```
//Receiver/Class code:

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "Hi", (sender) => {
    // do something whenever the "Hi" message is sent
});

//Sender/Main Page button Code:

MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, "Hi");
```

...

I expected the code to work in the sense that my class would actually execute but instead even in the very beginning of it all the code showed errors and wouldn't compile.

Comment: Please add information about the exact errors you get with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can a button from the main page call a class to enter information into the first page?

Sure, you could use [`MessagingCenter`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/MessagingCenter.cs#L23) send string from page1 to page2.

**Page1-> Page2**

Page2 need to subscribe Page1 class.

**Page2**

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page1, string>(this, "Tag", async (s, arg) =>
{
   await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        textblock.Text = arg;
    });

});
```

**Page1**

```
MessagingCenter.Send<Page1, string>(this, "Tag", "string parameter");
```